# Rails 4 - Google maps works in one view but not in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, associations, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to figure out how to get my gmaps4rails set up in my rails 4 app.

I have models called Address, Project and Profile.

The associations are:

Address

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

Profile

```
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Project

```
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

I have the same setup in both the projects and profiles scaffold. When i fill out the address form in the profile scaffold, the profile view correctly renders the map.

When I do the following in projects scaffold (which mirrors what I do in the profile scaffold), I get a blank white space where there should be a map.

Projects controller:

```
def show
    @invite = Invite.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @addresses = @project.addresses

      @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@addresses) do |address, marker|
        marker.lat address.latitude
        marker.lng address.longitude
        marker.infowindow address.full_address

      end
```

This is all just the same in the profile controller except it asks for @profile.addresses instead of @project.addresses (and everything works fine in profile view.

```
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.addresses.build



  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
     @project.addresses_build unless @project.addresses
  end
```

In the projects view partial:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=false&client=&key=&libraries=geometry&language=&hl=&region="></script>


<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script>
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setZoom(8);
});
</script>
```

when I inspect the element in chrome, in the projects view, I can see there is a div tag for map  and I can see the script is populated with an address (below)

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([{"lat":-33.858296,"lng":151.193575,"infowindow":"15 Pitt Street\u003cbr\u003eSydney   NSW   2000\u003cbr\u003eAustralia"}]);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setZoom(8);
});
```

- but no map is displayed.

Can anyone see where this is going wrong?

Comment: Are you using pjax or turbolinks?

Comment: turbolinks is set to false. I don't know what pjax is

Comment: it is something similar to turbolinks. Are there any console errors given from google maps?

Comment: no errors in the console inspector. it shows the same results for the page the works correctly as it does for the page that does not work